# Login to SMTP Server with Apache Commons Net

Tags: android, smtp, apache-commons-net

I'm trying to develop an Android application that takes a username and password from a user and checks his/her credentials against an email server. I just need to send the username and password combination to the email server and if the server accepts, then my application will consider the user to be authenticated.

I tried using Javamail, but apparently it doesn't get along with dalvik. Someone suggested that I try using Apache Commons, but I can't figure out how to get it to do what I need.

If anyone has any ideas, I greatly appreciate the help!

The server that I'm connecting to  uses IMAP/SMTP, by the way.

Update: Here's the code that I'm using to do the connect

```
client = new AuthenticatingSMTPClient();
client.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out), true));
client.connect(HOST, PORT);
client.login();
client.execTLS();
client.auth(AuthenticatingSMTPClient.AUTH_METHOD.PLAIN,user,pword);
```

And the server reply is :

```
220 pod51000.outlook.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Thu, 14 Feb 2013    18:52:33 +0000
HELO 10.71.12.99
250 pod51000.outlook.com Hello [66.76.192.214]
STARTTLS
220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready
AUTH PLAIN
503 5.5.2 Send hello first
```

I've never had to do anything like this before, so I just need a little direction on things like how to send "Hello", what else the server expects, etc.

Comment: You need this: http://commons.apache.org/net/api-3.2/org/apache/commons/net/smtp/package-summary.html - What's the problem you're facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! Added a client.helo() before authentication and it works beautifully